# Событие предзагрузки ресурса

Tags: c#, awesomium

День добрый.
Я использую Awesomium.NET, подскажите, как сделать событие загрузки ресурса из страницы?
Представим, у нас есть код:

```
<script src="somescript.js"></script>
<script src="src2.js"></script>
```

При открытии страницы они подгружаются.
Подскажите, как сделать событие, которое будет обрабатывать пред-подгрузку?
Желательно с возможностью изменения адреса для загрузки ресурса или его изменения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается следующим образом:

1. Создаёте класс, в котором реализуете интерфейс [`IResourceInterceptor`](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_IResourceInterceptor.htm)
2. В методе `OnRequest` выполняете обработку запрашиваемых элементов и модификацию ресурса, либо же возврат нового [ресурса](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_ResourceResponse.htm)

Например как-то так:

```
public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
{
    // тут проверка и, возможно манипуляции с ресурсом
    if(request.Url.Scheme == "http")
    {

    }


    return null; // или 
    // return new ResourceResponse.Create(string filename)...
}
```

3. Подключаете объект этого класса к WebCore

`WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = new MyResourceProcessor();`

Comment: Понял, спасибо!